# How to add mount options when SD card is auto-mounted in GNOME?

Tags: mount, nautilus, filesystem, automount, sd-card

I have an SD card that gets auto-mounted by the file manager (Nautilus in GNOME) when i put it in the reader on my laptop. However, I would like to be able to add some mount options like the ones in /etc/fstab when a card with a certain file system is inserted. Is that possible? Let's say the SD card is formatted with btrfs and I would like to add 'space_cache' as an option every time it's inserted, cold I do that somehow and still have the card be auto-mounted?

Answer (score 1):

Read the `/etc/fstab` file, `man 5 fstab` and `man blkid` and [the community help on UUIDs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingUUID). You will end up adding something like this to `/etc/fstab` (note the use of the `noauto` option to silence boot-time complaints) YMMV:

```
UUID=24D5-05A4 /home/w3/mnt/Jellybeans/Green    vfat nodev,nosuid,noexec,user,noauto,rw 0 0
```

Comment: Just to make sure I get this: that fstab entry will be applied every time I add that particular card to the reader?

Comment: That line of `/etc/fstab` will be applied when the system mounts any device with that UUID.

Comment: Thank you so much. Worked out great with a btrfs formatted 256 GB card.